# What is the significance of dumping the tablespaces?

Tags: database, drush

While recently running `drush sql-dump` on a server where there were never any error messages, I have started to get:

> mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces

It still produces a file I can import locally and I don't seem to be having any problems. But I am still curious: What *is* the significance of dumping the tablespaces when it comes to the average Drupal sysadmin?

**Environment**

- Drush: Drush Commandline Tool 10.3.2
- Drupal: 8.9.13
- DB: Server version: 5.7.31-34-log Percona Server (GPL), Release '34', Revision '2e68637'
- Acquia Cloud hosted

Comment: Can you please add the versions of Drush, Drupal and mysql to your post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tablespaces are used to define the physical file location of one (or more) tables - chances are if you were using them for something beyond the default innodb space, you'd know about it. It's likely safe to ignore.

The error will have started when MySQL was updated to 5.7.something, they introduced a breaking change in a minor version because it addressed a security flaw, and world + dog was greeted with this error message.

There's a way around it:

```
drush sql:dump --extra-dump=--no-tablespaces
```

or, if using drush 8:

```
drush sql:dump --extra=--no-tablespaces
```

Comment: 5.7.31 was the version that introduced this breaking change.

Comment: The drush issue for this is https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4489

Comment: And this also happens with mysql 8.0.21+

Comment: Drush 10: --extra-dump is correct: https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/sql_dump/